# Bluetooth sending all String in one time (not bit by bit only whole byte at once)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, serial-port

In my mobile robot project, which have 2 servo motors to rotate the camera in two planes I want to control them in my android app by rotation the smartphone (through readings yaw/pitch/roll from the smartphone accelometer).

For that I have to send data about this three angles through Bluetooth to Arduino. So for example sample data packet looks like

> "Y:100,P:20,R:45"

where [Y-yaw, P-pitch,R-roll]. However, when I try to send this kind of data packet through Bluetooth from my smartphone to Arduino, in Arduino the packet is received bit by bit, so above shown data packet in Serial Port Monitor looks like:

- Y
- :
- 1
- 0
- 0

  etc. (which makes it much harder to read this data and their correct acquisition, because my smartphone sends as well other data to control the direction of mobile robot [engines]).

So if I using smartphone + Bluetooth + Arduino -> it is possible to send a whole packet of data at once, no bit by bit ???

This is the code from Android Studio (about Bluetooth Activity):

```
  package com.samplecompass;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;


public class cBluetooth{

    public final static String TAG = "BL_4WD";

    private static BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private OutputStream outStream = null;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

    // SPP UUID service
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    private final Handler mHandler;
    public final static int BL_NOT_AVAILABLE = 1;        // ������ ��� Handler
    public final static int BL_INCORRECT_ADDRESS = 2;
    public final static int BL_REQUEST_ENABLE = 3;
    public final static int BL_SOCKET_FAILED = 4;
    public final static int RECIEVE_MESSAGE = 5;

    cBluetooth(Context context, Handler handler){
        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mHandler = handler;
        if (btAdapter == null) {
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(BL_NOT_AVAILABLE);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void checkBTState() {
        if(btAdapter == null) {
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(BL_NOT_AVAILABLE);
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth ON");
            } else {
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(BL_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            }
        }
    }

    public void BT_Connect(String address) {
        Log.d(TAG, "...On Resume...");

        if(!BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(address)){
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(BL_INCORRECT_ADDRESS);
            return;
        }
        else{
            BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            try {
                btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage());
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(BL_SOCKET_FAILED);
                return;
            }

            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
            try {
                btSocket.connect();
                Log.d(TAG, "...Connection ok...");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    btSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage());
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(BL_SOCKET_FAILED);
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
            Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

            try {
                outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage());
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(BL_SOCKET_FAILED);
                return;
            }

            mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread();
            mConnectedThread.start();
        }
    }

    public void BT_onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "...On Pause...");
        if (outStream != null) {
            try {
                outStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage());
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(BL_SOCKET_FAILED);
                return;
            }
        }

        if (btSocket != null) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage());
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(BL_SOCKET_FAILED);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendData(String message) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

        Log.i(TAG, "Send data: " + message);

        if (outStream != null) {
            try {
                outStream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage());
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(BL_SOCKET_FAILED);
                return;
            }
        } else Log.d(TAG, "Error Send data: outStream is Null");
    }

/**
public void write(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        outStream.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
}
**/
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

        private final InputStream mmInStream;

        public ConnectedThread() {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = btSocket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't bit by bit, what you get. It is byte by byte. So you receive (ASCII): `089  058 049 048 048`  (Y:100). This could be helpfull to understand. Also there is a function called `readString()`, that might be helpfull https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadString . Otherwise you can build your own string in a function with something like: `while(Serial.available()){ // AddCharToStringCode}`

Comment: That's how serial works. The problem is with your Arduino code (which you didn't show), that assumes the data is received in a single chunk.

Comment: @H.Puc I can't use `while(Serial.available()){ // AddCharToStringCode}`, because I send through Bluetooth to Arduino another data like "w","e","d","c","x","z","a","q","?" when I touch virtual joystick to control direction my mobile robot (in the same Activity -> MainActivity) unless I use in my packet data some header & footer and pseudo code like `if(BluetoothData == 'header') {
do{//AddCharToStringCode}
}while(BluetoothData!='footer'}` to distinguish data packet ???

Comment: @gre_gor This is Arduino code to gather and print BluetoothData -> `BluetoothData = (int)Serial.read(); Serial.println((char)BluetoothData`